# Tizen .NET Visual Studio can't debug

Tags: .net, visual-studio, xamarin, tizen, tizen-emulator

I installed VS 2017, Tizen SDK, Emulator, all is ok.
After to launch emulator, I can't debug with visual studio? 
I have this output on VS:

> pkg api_version: 4
>   =thread-selected,id="1" 
> Loaded '[vdso]'. Cannot find or open the symbol file.
>  Loaded 'linux-gate.so.1'. Cannot find or open the symbol
>   file. 
>  Le thread 0x1 s'est arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0). 
> Le programme
>   'sdb.exe' s'est arrêté avec le code 0 (0x0).

I can just install with command line with sdb.exe install "xxxx.tpk"

Thank you!

Comment: FWIW I have the same issue.  As a workaround I am logging to a file under /opt/usr/home/owner/share and I can then pull it using sdb.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I can install it, or pull it inside the directory, but can't debug with Visual Studio 2017...

Comment: I have some errors with my app, and I cannot see which one :-(

Answer (score 2):

Sorry for inconvenience on using Tizen extension.
This caused by compatible issue with VS 15.8. We fixed our extension and our patch is under internal testing now.
It will be available on the begin of November at the Marketplace.

Comment: I have the same problem with both VS2017 and 2019 and the Tizen TV 5.5 emulator with everything up to date. Do you have any suggestions?